# Some questions on Fedora 9

Tags: fedora

Currently I have Fedora 9 dual boot with Vista.

1) Can I do upgrade directly from fedora 9 to Fedora 13? If yes, How?

2) When I plug my earphones, the output on speakers does not stop. I can hear from both. HOw to rectify that?

3) I installed VLC through yum install. But clicking VLC icon does not do anything. Which is the best media player for Fedora with all the codecs which can all files including rm and flv.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask only **ONE** thing per question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No you can't, read the [upgrade guide](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/YumUpgradeFaq).
2. You need to install newer driver, or better yet, install a new version of Fedora
3. [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), it's in the repos. Make sure you add [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/), though.

Since you have such an old version of Fedora, which isn't supported anymore for so long, I advice backing up your home directory and install anew, with Fedora 13.

As a personal advice: If you don't must, don't dual boot. Use a VM like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). I have 18 operating systems of different kinds installed in VMs right now, and use F13 as host OS.